# Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations'

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I am trying to set up an Instrumented Unit Tests for my App. and I have added dependency based on the below developer site link.

https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html#build

This is my dependency list

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
}
```

When I build the project I am getting the below compile error:

```
Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':MyApp'. Resolved versions for the app (21.0.3) and test app (24.0.0) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
```

Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annotations is the part of Support library. So,your annotations and support library version Should be same and you have to call forcefully by using below code .This code should be placed above dependencies.For more detail  [See here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020/blob/05a57bf43b9b61f16d32cbe8717af77cd608b0fb/build.gradle#L136-L140)

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.3'
  }
}
```

Comment: i have changed to 21.0.3, now i am getting this error Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':MyApp'. Resolved versions for app (21.0.3) and test app (23.1.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.